# What am i doing wrong in this css/html?

Tags: html, css

here is some code from the css

```
#linkheader/*Links bar for access to other parts of the website*/
 {
    width:900px;
    border-radius:25px;
    margin:20px 50px 0px 0px;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px dotted orange;
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    color:orange;
    background-color:rgba(20,10,10,0.7);
}
.sourcelinkheader
{
width:1000px;
}
#content /*Material Container for Sources and Index*/
 {
    width:1000px;
    margin:10px auto;
    border:2px solid orange;
    background-color:rgba(20,10,10,0.7);
}
```

html body

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>Information and Image Sources</h1>
</div>
    <div id="linkheader" class="sourcelinkheader">
    <p>
        <p><a href="index.html">Index</a> -
        <a href="Verkhluti_1.html">Introduction</a> -
        <a href="Verkhluti_1_katana.html">Nihontō</a> -
        <a href="Verkhluti_1_zweihander.html">Great Sword</a> -
        <a href="Verkhluti_1_gladius.html">Gladius</a> -
        <a href="Verkhluti_1_european swords.html">European</a> -
        <a href="Verkhluti_1_fencing.html">Fencing</a> -
        <a href="Verkhluti_1_source.html">Sources</a>
    </p>
</div>
    <div id= "content">
        <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword"><img src=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bb/Wikipedia_wordmark.svg/174px-Wikipedia_wordmark.svg.png alt="Wikipedia"></a>
        <p><a href="http://www.weedhopper.org/">Metal Bakgrunnstextíll</a></p>
    </div>
<div class= "footer">
</div>
</body>
```

[image: Result]

My desired result is that the linkheader's width becomes 1000px and i want it to be located above "content" not inside of it.

What did i do wrong?

As requested, http://jsfiddle.net/zjd9d/

Comment: if you really wrote `width:1000;` units (px) are missing here. And you uncorrectly nested a `<p>` inside another `<p>` (without closing it)

Comment: you also have `width:900px;` for linkheader.

Comment: i changed width:1000; to width:1000px; didn't have any effect.

Comment: +1 for really good formulated question, with all information needed(even a screeenshot)

Comment: if you create a jsfiddle of the example we can help you better

Comment: **Dipesh Parmar** is right your css entry **#linkheader** overrides the **.scourcelinkheader** due to the specficity of the selectors. and if this is the actual code, i would check what **Fabrizio Calderan** wrote about the <p>- tags

Answer (score 3):

```
float:right;
```

Add the above code in your Content style will fix this and get to what i believe you need here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/qbBk6/2/

Answer (score 1):

The width of the linkheader is defined twice, first through an id: `#linkheader` and then through a class `.sourcelinkheader`.

Even though `width: 1000px;` has been set on the second rule, the first one is more specific (id instead of class) so the first one applies (read more on specificity here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 0):

this is how i fixed it.

I changed my css code to this.

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/HzK9U/)

```
#linkheader/*Links bar for access to other parts of the website*/
 {
    width:900px;
    border-radius:25px;
    margin:20px 50px 0px 0px;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px dotted orange;
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    color:orange;
    background-color:rgba(20,10,10,0.7);
}
#linkheader.sourcelinkheader
{
float:none;
margin: 10px auto;
width:1000px;
}
```

The thing that fixed it for me was changing

```
.sourcelinkheader
```

to

```
#linkheader.sourcelinkheader
```

and removing the float from it and using margin instead. (Since all windows were supposed to be centered.)

Comment: finally managed to get the answer right. stackoverflow didn't accept my code indentation the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Rabcor you can easily achieve your desired result through simple css how i did it :

Just removed `float:right` and gave the `width:1000;` to your id `#linkheader`

and its working fine....

**CSS**

```
#linkheader
/*Links bar for access to other parts of the website*/
 {
    width:1000px;
    border-radius:25px;
    margin:20px 50px 0px 20px;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px dotted orange;
    text-align:center;
    color:orange;
    background-color:rgba(20, 10, 10, 0.7);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zjd9d/1/)